# Is there an Oracle API to implement readonly views over a structured sequence of bytes

Tags: oracle, rdbms

Suppose I want to use an Oracle database, and  I have some flat binary file containing structured data. Suppose I have a relational model that fits this data structure.

Does Oracle provide an API to implement some adapter to be able to relationally query this sequence of bytes as a set of views?

If so:

- where should the data reside?
- what version offers this feature?

If no:

- is there any other RDBMS that offers such an API?

Comment: Half of your title I could understand, it is clear, the second half needs a little bit more of detailing. Can you add some sample of this so called data structure? I'm asking because depending on what this data structure is you may have an entire different answer.

Comment: You _might_ be able to do what you want with table functions (can be implemented in PL/SQL but also in C or Java). Whether that's a good idea or not I have no idea. Might want to poke around the "Oracle Data Cartridge" docs too - of which I know essentially nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [external table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm#i1007478). Normally, external tables must use text columns, but you can use the `PREPROCESSOR` directive to specify a script that will transform the source file before loading it.

You could also use `UTL_FILE` to load the table from disk and do whatever you want to it in the database. This could include a pipelined table function that you access with the `TABLE` operator.